# Using fixtures with sequel-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures, sequel

I'm working on an existing Rails 4.0 project that is using Sequel for the ORM rather than ActiveRecord via the `sequel-rails` gem.  There are no tests for this application currently.  I am trying to write some tests that load fixtures from YAML files similar to the Rails guides recommend (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures).  I've not been successful thus far trying to get fixtures loaded.  Are there any recommendations or guides for testing a Rails application using Sequel?

I found a gem by Jeremy Evans, fixture_dependencies (https://github.com/jeremyevans/fixture_dependencies), which seems promising.  It advertises that it works for Sequel and ActiveRecord but I get an error when calling the `fixtures` class method.

Here's my setup:

1. In `config/application.rb`, I've disabled ActiveRecord as the `sequel-rails` github page outlines:

   ```
   #require 'rails/all'
   require 'action_controller/railtie'
   #require 'active_record/railtie'
   require 'action_mailer/railtie'
   require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'
   require 'sprockets/railtie'
   ```
2. In `test/test_helper.rb`, I've required `fixture_dependencies`:

   ```
   ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
   require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
   require 'rails/test_help'
   require 'fixture_dependencies/test_unit/sequel'

   require 'minitest/focus'
   require 'minitest/reporters'

   Minitest::Reporters.use! Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter.new

   class ActiveSupport::TestCase
     # Disabling the following since we are not using ActiveRecord
     #ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!

     fixtures :all

   end
   ```

When I run my tests, I get the following error:

```
➜ bundle exec rake
rake aborted!
undefined method `fixtures` for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class
```

Comment: Have you considered using Factories instead of Fixtures? Take a look at factory_girl gem.

Comment: I have but I would like to have both options available.  I'd like to be able to start tests with a common set of test data in the database.

Comment: *Why?* By running your tests against a clean slate you will catch bugs that can be masked by having a bunch of fixtures hanging around. A very common bug is views or controllers that break when the table is empty.

Comment: A concrete example is when developer A decides that having a bunch of Foo's around in the test environment is convenient and developer B creates a feature and forgets to check `if Foo.any?`. The tests pass and it is pushed to production which crashes since there are no Foo's. Or when people check the count in a test after saving and it is 1 even though no record was created.

Comment: @TylerAmos did you manage to get it working? I'm stuck on the same problem: trying to get a simple hello world fixture running using sequel, rather than activerecord. on pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I'm sorry.  I don't recall now if I got this working.  It was so long ago :(